# How to get the last iterator by using find_if?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use `find_if` in a function with Lambda Expressions. I would like to get the last iterator of the vector, but I am not sure how to write it.

I can get the first iterator with this code. In this code, struct has an index and score. A vector in the code save structs and if an index is multiplies of five, the score is higher than usual. In this code, the first iterator's index is five and the last iterator's index is 25.

```cpp
struct Recorder
{
    Recorder(int idx, float score)
    {
        this->idx = idx;
        this->score = score;
    }

    int idx;
    float score;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Recorder>> recorders;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        float score = 0.3;
        bool isLost = false;
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) score = 0.8;
        std::shared_ptr<Recorder> poseRecord = std::make_shared<Recorder>(i, score);
        recorders.push_back(poseRecord);
    }


    auto record = std::find_if(recorders.begin(), recorders.end(),
        [](const std::shared_ptr<Recorder>& r) {
        return (r->score >= 0.8f);
    });


    std::cout << "idx : " << (*record)->idx << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the last iterate in this code? (here `(*record)->idx` should be 25).

Comment: Use reverse_iterator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reverse iterators to start the search from the other end. Also, as Fureeish and Ted pointed out in the comments, it's more efficient to pass the shared pointer to the lambda function as reference.

```
auto record = std::find_if(recorders.rbegin(), recorders.rend(),
    [&](const std::shared_ptr<Recorder> & r) {
    return (r->isLost == false && r->score >= 0.8f);
});
```

Comment: I would advise you to advise the OP to **not** pass `std::shared_ptr` by value. It performs reference-count operations on copy and destruction, which may be a significant hit for the performance.

Comment: What @Fureeish said. Make the lambda `[](const std::shared_ptr<Recorder>& r)` instead.

Comment: @Fureeish Thanks for the advice. Isn't a normal pointer also appropriate here instead of using a smart_pointer?

Comment: @Masahiro A `unique_ptr` (or `shared_ptr`) is almost always prefered over a raw pointer.